# Is $f(Y | X)$ in the same family as $f(Y)$?

Tags: conditional-probability

Is it the case that for random variables $Y$ and $X$, $f(Y | X)$ in the same family as $f(Y)$?

If so how can I prove it? If not are there any situations (some families of distributions) where they can be the same? Or is it related to the link function(s)?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some specific cases where it is true, such as a bivariate normal, then $f(Y)$ and $f(Y|X)$ are both normal.

But consider the case where $f(Y|X)$ is normal (with mean depending on $X$) and $X$ follows a uniform distribution.  Then $f(Y)$ is not normally distributed.

There are also distributions where the marginals ($f(X)$ and $f(Y)$) are both $\text{uniform}(0,1)$, but there is a hole in the square where the probability is $0$, so the conditional $f(Y|X)$ would not be uniform and for some values of $X$ would be disjoint.

Comment: +1, this is the right answer. For an *illustration* (eg, pictures) of how $f(Y)$ & $f(Y|X)$ can differ, there are some at my answer here: [What if residuals are normally distributed but Y is not?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12262//33320#33320)

Comment: What about members of exponential family? Or distributions with -inf->inf support? Can we relate $f(Y), f(X), f(Y|X)$ in some way?

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc, I have seen a bivariate distribution where both marginals are normal, but there is a hole of 0 probability in the center (where the bivariate normal would have the highest probability), so for that distribution f(Y|X) is certainly not normal (may be approximate for some values of X, but clearly not when passing through the hole).

Comment: @Greg, what if the distributions are nice? Meaning they are smooth, no discontinuities, support from -inf to +inf.

Comment: Being 'nice' doesn't solve the problem; You can have both margins and the conditionals all 'nice' ... but still not of the same form, even with normal margins.